# Unable to reference webservice (.asmx) in my ASP.NET Project

Tags: .net, asp.net

[image]In my current project, I have a webservice file called MyServices.asmx. This webservice I want to reference in my Default.aspx.cs file.

**My Code**:

```
    MyServices newService = new MyServices();

    newService.addUser(txFirstName.Text, txLastName.Text, txtEmail.Text, 
txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtBalance.Text);
```

---

But when I refer to that webservice (as shown below), I get error saying:
"***The type or namespace name 'MyServices' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***"

What should I do to correct this error?

Current Solution of Adding Service Reference still gives me that error. Can you please suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you add the web reference to that web service to the references?

Comment: What is the point of calling a web service from the same project as itself? You're creating layered web requests on top of each other (which adds latency). Both the web service and the default page should call some extracted logic in a separate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem by creating another webservice file.

Instead of MyService.asmx, I created a new one called MyServ.asmx and copied the code from MyService.asmx

By doing that, I was able to get the webservice reference in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a service reference to it.

In the project holding the Default.aspx.cs file, right click on "Service References" -> Add service reference.

You can then just click the "Discover" button to have the webservice listed.
Select it and click "OK".

Comment: When I right click on Default.aspx.cs file, I dont see Service Reference....can you please help

Comment: My webservice is currently hosted on localhost only. So if I add it as service reference, will it work fine if I move this project to Production?

Comment: @meetpd: It won't work. I kindly suggest you move your service logic in a separated class or method and use it directly in your code. If you want to stick with it anyways, you'll have to change the endpoint in runtime (this should be a different question maybe):  `myServiceClient.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://myNewAddress");`

Comment: Ok. I have managed to upload the webservice to Production server. I had added webreference to this webservice. Still I get the same error. Do I have to remove MyServices.asmx file and MyServices.cs from my project?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you added the reference and called the reference MyServices when you added it...

MyServices is the  name you gave the reference when you added it.  You need to find the name of the actual service.

For example, we have a web services website, and it contains many different web services (asmx files).  Assume we have one called EmployeeInformationService

In Visual Studio, I might add a reference to it and choose the name "MyServices" as you did.  To reference it in code I would need to put:

```
MyServices.EmployeeInformationService  newService = new MyServices.EmployeeInformationService();
```